# PHP function to fetch data as arrays and display

Tags: php, function, mysqli

I came up with this piece of code from others work to gather data from database and display it the simplest and safest way without loop. However it doesn't really work and I would like to know why?
So my main question is how to make it work?
And the 2:nth how to make it as secure as possible?

Code to display data:

```
<?php echo $webdata['web_name']; ?>
```

Code in init.php:

```
$webdata = webdata('id', 'web_name');
```

Code for function:

```
function webdata($data) {
    $web_data = array();
    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    global $db_connect;
    if ($func_num_args > 1) {
        unset($func_get_args[0]);
        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';

        $query = "SELECT $fields FROM `settings` WHERE id = 1";
        $result = $db_connect->query($query);
        while ($web_data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            return ($web_data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason you put the return in a while loop? You're just going to be returning the first row; in this case it would make more sense to remove the loop and have `return $result->fetch_assoc();`

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox Thank you for reply, however I get this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\WebServer\htdocs\peinture_project\lib\functions\functions.php on line 26` which means that my query failed but don't know why?

Comment: But it doesn't give an error in the loop? What's the output from `var_dump($result)`?

Comment: It gives error on loop aswell, it gives `bool(false)`

Comment: OK then the query is failing. Even if it returned nothing, it would still give an empty result set. If it gets that far, then you're connected to the db. Two things: 1. Since the query is failing there should be an error, so type `if (!($result = $db_connect->query($query)) echo $db_connect->error();`. What's the error message? 2. `echo $query` and see what that puts out - there's most likely an issue with the `$fields` variable since everything else is hard-coded.

Comment: No 1. Did not work and shows `Call to undefined method mysqli::error()`  and No 2. `echo $query` will output `SELECT $fields FROM settings WHERE id = 1`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36170/discussion-between-chicagoredsox-and-drikane)

Answer (score 0):

- You don't have a `data` variable from the query. You have a `webdata` variable however...

Instead:

```
while ($webdata = $result->fetch_assoc()) { return ($data); }
```

Use:

```
while ($webdata = $result->fetch_assoc()) { return ($webdata); }
```

- You just return the first row, is this what you want?
- You don't use the $data variable, what should it be for?

This is as secure as it gets: you don't have any means inject something into the query...

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, however I've updated code, you might wanna check it out now.